# Combining two different types of plots into one window using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say that I have two data frames defined in such way :

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:3, 3), val=sample(1:100, 9), 
                 variable='category')
df1 <- data.frame(x=rep(4:6, 3), val=sample(1:100, 9), 
                 variable='category')
```

And I want to plot them both on one graph in such way that for x from 1 to 3 it would be the line, and for x from 4 to 6 it would be dots. So

```
plot_1<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=val))+geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
plot_2<-ggplot(data=df1,aes(x=x,y=val))+geom_point(aes(colour=variable))
plot_grid(plot_1,plot_2,nrow = 1,ncol=1)
```

And in output I get the graph following :

[image]

So instead of line from 1 to 3 and dots from 4 to 6 I have just the first graph (line from 1 till 3).

Is there some easy way how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your `plot_grid` command is wrong. You can not have one row and one column with two plots. It should be `plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, nrow = 1)` or `plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, ncol = 1)`. But maybe the solution of Ronak Shah looks nicer.

Comment: But then you have two graphs instead of one

Comment: That's true. `plot_grid` is intended to put multiple graphs next to (or above) each other. If you want one graph then the solution of Ronak Shah is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot the data on the same graph you can try :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + aes(x, val) + 
   geom_line(data = df) + geom_point(data = df1)
```

[image]